# useState not evaluating after history.push

Tags: reactjs

Are there any issues with history.push and useState?

Relevant part of my code

```
import { useParams, useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
const Component = () => {
    const history = useHistory()
    const { search } = useLocation()
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
    const [name, setName] = useState(searchParams.get('name') || '' )
    
    const onClickButton = () => {
        history.push(`/items?page=1`) // New URL doesn't have name
    }
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log(name)
    }, [search])
    
    return (
      <button onClick={onClickButton}>Click</button>
    )
```

Now suppose my current URL is

```
/items?name=Apples
```

And then I have a button, when clicked, will route the user to

```
/items?page=1
```

However, for some reason,

```
const [name, setName] = useState(searchParams.get('name') || '' )
```

Evaluates to

```
Apple
```

Even though the useLocation.search() will only have

```
?page=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that's passed to useState is used as default value, it won't trigger new updates even there is new change, you should use combination with useEffect or use normal variable instead.

```js
const [name, setName] = useState(searchParams.get('name') || '' )

useEffect(() => {
    setName(searchParams.get('name'));
}, [searchParams.get('name')])
```

or

```js
const name = searchParams.get('name') || ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the name state to any new value here - useState() takes an initial value as an argument, it won't set the state to that value for each render. So for example, when you initially set your `name` state, it will evaluate `searchParams.get('name')` and assign that value to `name`. On each subsequent render, however, only a call to `setName` will change the `name` state, it will not evaluate the initial value function argument again.